# local member referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, pygame

I get this error "local member event referenced before assignment" in the following code.

```
for event in event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
         sys.exit
```

I even tried added `global event` before the beginning of for loop but then I'll get an error saying "event member not defined".

Can anybody please help me with this ?

Comment: `for event in event.get():` - hmm, an event "gets" itself? This is a slightly odd case, if event is indeed declared to be global, but the basic solution is to use a different (local) variable name for the loop.

Comment: have you tried `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` and/or `for event in pygame.event.get():`? and your missing parenthesis on `sys.exit` (should be `sys.exit()`)

Comment: Could it be that you are using the same variable name `event` for the iterated item and the iterator? Maybe `for evt in event.get():`

Comment: I was doing `from pygame import*` and because of that I didn't have to use pygame.something anywhere.

I changed it to import pygame and did pygame.something everywhere including pygame.event.get() and it worked. Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example from the pygame docs:

```
import random, time, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
...
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:      #event is quit 
        terminate()
```

I'm guessing the problem is that you've imported pygame.event, so you're getting a name conflict. Change your import to just import pygame (and use the qualified reference `pygame.event`) or else, as suggested, use a different name for your iterator variable.